# Вывод изображения android

Tags: изображения, java, android

Существует набор изображений, со случайными показателями ширины и высоты. Изображения должны выступать в качестве заднего фона, но мне не совсем понятно как работать с изображениями, которые многократно превышают размеры экрана и имеют большое различие в длинны и ширины. Единственное что приходит на ум, обрезать изображение до пропорций экрана и делать scaletype="fiTxy". Есть ли более рациональное и быстрое решенеие?

Comment: Не совсем понял, в чём проблема и что требуется?

Изображение будет в качестве фон и растянуто по ширине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ничего не надо обрезать, то делай так:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.image);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
```

где R.drawable.image - картинка, которую необходимо сжать,
width - до этой ширины надо сжать,
height - до этой высоты.